# REST How can I combine search entity and attributes at the same time

Tags: rest, query-string, url-parameters

Hello Everyone I hate these entities in REST

```
{
    "id": "Church-MX-1",
    "type": "PointOfInterest",
    "category": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Church",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "geo:point",
        "value": "19.435433, -99.133072",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Catedral Metropolitana",
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "postalAddress": {
        "type": "StructuredValue",
        "value": {
            "addressCountry": "MX",
            "addressLocality": "México Ciudad de México",
            "addressRegion": "Ciudad de México"
        },
        "metadata": {}
    },
    "source": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "http://www.arquidiocesismexico.org.mx",
        "metadata": {}
    }
},
```

What i want to do is to perform a query using Insomnia where i can get type = PointOfInterest AND also by "name"."value" = "Catedral Metropolitana".

How can I do this?

I tried this query but is not working:

```
http://148.205.176.167:1026/v2/entities?limit=100&type=PointOfInterest&name=%22Catedral%20Metropolitana%22
```

It is not working because it displays all **PointOfInterest** and not only the one with name "Catedral Metropolitana".

I tried to find resources on queries in REST but just found the requests and nothing on how to query entities.

I hope someone can help me please. I will keep searching.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

[NGSIv2 Documentation](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/)

Have to use the right operators for it, according to Simple Query Standard.

So the query for this is:

```
http://148.205.176.167:1026/v2/entities?type=PointOfInterest&q=name~%3DBellas%20Artes
```

name like Bellas Artes is `q=name~=Bellas Artes` and insomnia does the url Encoding.